# Issue adding transparent background on my background-image

Tags: html, css

I'm only trying to add a black transparent background layer on my image using `:before` but nothing appears:

Here is my snippet:

```css
.card {
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("assets/images/11.webp") no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}
.card:before {
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: #19191b;
  background-color: var(--black);
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -webkit-opacity: 0.8;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: 0.8;
  content: "";
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-clip: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="card customcard1">
   <h3 className="cardTitle">card header</h3>
   <p className="cardPara">card paragraph</p>
   <p className="cardPara">card paragraph</p>
   <p className="cardPara">card paragraph</p>
   <p className="cardPara">card paragraph</p>
   <p className="cardPara">card paragraph</p>

 </div>
```

```
.card {
  padding: 2rem 3rem;

  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("assets/images/11.webp") no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}
.card:before {
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: #19191b;
  background-color: var(--black);
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -webkit-opacity: 0.8;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: 0.8;
  content: "";
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-clip: border-box;
}
<div class="card">
          <h3 className="cardTitle">card header</h3>
          <h3 className="cardTitle">card header</h3>
          <h3 className="cardTitle">card header</h3>
          <h3 className="cardTitle">card header</h3>
          <h3 className="cardTitle">card header</h3>
          <h3 className="cardTitle">card header</h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: Shorthand CSS `background-color` would be the first value. ex. `background: #000 url(http://example.com/pic.png) no-repeat;`. Using the `::before` pseudo-element will most likely overcomplicate and ultimately hinder your efforts to style anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `z-index:0` in `.card::before` ;) it overwrites your `z-index:99` and make the selector fall behind .card